# Get the timestamps in java

Tags: java, timestamp, gregorian-calendar

I want to get the actuel timestamp and add 5 seconds to it . I tried this code

```
            java.util.Calendar cal = new java.util.GregorianCalendar(2007, 9 - 1, 23);
           // Current time would be....
            java.util.Calendar cal2 = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println("Instance before : "+ cal2.getTimeInMillis());
            cal2.add(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 5);
            System.out.println("Instance after : "+ cal2.getTimeInMillis());
```

Output

> Instance before : 1390785186301 Instance after : 1390785191301

I don't think that this output is a correct timestamp. I tried the two result in an online website and it work only if I delete the last 3 numbers 1390785186 , and the second one is +5 milliseconds
[image: timestamp 1]
[image: timestamps 2]

Comment: The second number is 5000 milleseconds (ie, 5 secs) more than the second. What more would you like?

Answer (score 1):

The website you looked at is using unix time which is SECONDS since 1970. Java uses MILLISECONDS since 1970. Java time is more precise but you need to divide by 1000 to get seconds.